# reporting services anonymous access to reports

Tags: reporting-services, anonymous-access

I can't create a NT account for everyone that need access to the reports.
Does anyone know or have a link to the info to allow anonymous access to reporting services reports ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, I had tried it before but was failing, tried again and worked fine, must have missed something the first time around.

The steps are very simple:

1. Standard install of SSRS 2005
   (Integrated authentication)
2. In
   IIS, duplicate the ReportingServices
   virtual directory and name it Public
3. Under Public properties set
   Directory Security - Authentication
   and Access Control - to Enable
   Anonymous access using the
   IUSR_ account. Uncheck
   all other access types.
4. Using the
   report manager, set up a folder
   named Public, and added the
   IUSR_ account to the
   Public directory role manager with a
   viewonly role. (Assuming you have
   already established a viewonly role
   as one with only the 'view reports'
   task enabled.)
5. Add any other
   types of administrative/developer
   accounts

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous access is no longer a simple configuration for MS SQL Reporting Services 2008.  I started on that path and ended up integrating Reporting Services into our existing security system.  You could follow [these instructions](http://agilemusings.blogspot.com/2009/11/reporting-services-2008-custom-security.html) to achieve anonymous access also.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is on a windows domain you can grant access to a group eg. `Domain Users`

Answer (score 0):

In case it may help - particularly with `SSRS 2008`

It depends on the autentication type you have choosen, with basic auth you may achieve this. However, if it is in corporate environment, why not use the `RSWindowsKerberos`, `RSWindowsNegotiate`, `RSWindowsNTLM` - as far as users are members of the domain, they use integrated authentication.

You will get better security and flexibility and consolidation of access rights. Please also don't forget to use the built in networkservices as service account for your reporter, if you use domain account you will definitely need registration of SPN at your domain controller.