# How to access the reporting server without using a VPN?

Tags: reporting-services, rdp

It might sound a bit of a unorganized architecture but this is what I am doing

I am working on a machine that is situated in location A and I connect through VPN to a RDP at location B which has sql server 2008 R2 installed on it.

I work from machine A and develop the SSRS reports on the RDP at location B.

if I want to view the reports I just log into the RDP and enter the report server url which redirects me to the report.

Now the problem is that I want others to view the SSRS reports which are residing on RDP at location B. Is it possible that the users don't login to the rdp using vpn but view the reports just by entering the url for the report from any machine. Just like a website?

If not what is the best possible method that I can implement to make the reports public.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the question if can they view reports on B using vpn without opening remote desktop than it should be as much as making sure that firewalls or vpn (other network stuff) is not blocking traffic to b on SSRS http port. If your asking hot to get to reportserver without VPN then your looking into how to publish it to web or perhaps how to link your networks this is very broad question then. Please specify ?

Answer (score 1):

As location B isn't part of domain A then you can't access to the report server from A. You should implement anonymous access to the reports, but it isn't simple task. You can refer to this thread for more information [reporting services anonymous access to reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357500/reporting-services-anonymous-access-to-reports)